# RM-ANOVA vs Mixed Model

Tags: mixed-model, anova, linear-model, levenes-test

I am trying to find the best analysis approach for my data.

Simply put, I am looking at a treatment for the impacts of drug exposure before birth.
My groups are:

1 - no drug, no treatment

2 - **drug**, no treatment

3 - no drug, **treatment**

4 - **drug, treatment**

In each group, there are 5-7 pairs so siblings (1 male, 1 female from each mother, so 5-7 mothers per group) - so 10-14 participants in total.
However, as they are related I do not want to treat the siblings as independent from one another, as the mothering style etc could have an impact on the data I am collecting (although not something I am particularly interested in). Additionally, I want to consider if the drug and treatment are having different impacts in males or females.

Thus far I had been using a RM ANOVA in SPSS with the siblings as within-subjects variables, and drug and treatment as between-subjects variables (e.g. drug 1 or 2 [no exposure or exposure] and treatment 1 or 2 [treatment or no treatment]).

However, there are some issues with this.

For some of my data sets I am missing data from one of a pair of siblings (sometimes multiple times), meaning the data from the other sibling is lost, reducing my power, obviously an issue when I already have small group numbers.

For some measures, I have significant p values for Levene's test of equality of variances and I am struggling to find an appropriate alternative parametric test.

My group sizes are unequal.

I'm sure there are other issues I am unaware of in this set up.

I am very unfamiliar with linear mixed modeling, and no one in my lab etc uses it, but it has come up a few times as a potentially more appropriate test.

Alternatively, I would also consider analyzing the sexes separately from one another. Or as a within-subjects variable in a univariate ANOVA but I would loose the ability to control so sibling effects.

So I guess my questions are

1. Is an RM ANOVA appropriate here, and if not what would be a more appropriate test?
2. If I do continue to use RM ANOVAs what is the appropriate response to a significant Levene's test?
3. If I were to change to a mixed model, what might that set look like and what are the appropriate follow-up tests to an interaction?

I have ended up doing research in an area requiring stats I am not familiar with (clearly) and have very minimal support available to me, so any help would be greatly appreciated.